# Проблема с воспроизведением плеера

Tags: java, android, массивы

Проблема такова:
case R.id.b1: выбрал сработала анимация+музыка,выбираю case R.id.b2: остановился плеер и анимация и мне необходимо нажать второй раз для воспроизведения case R.id.b2:
как можно избежать повторного клика? Я знаю,что в методе проверяю и останавливаю плеер,но это если я повторно нажму case R.id.b1:,т.е проверка на играющий плеер нужна

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     stopAnimation();

        switch (v.getId()) {
    //imageview1
            case R.id.b1: {
                v.startAnimation(anim);

                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);

                break;
            }
//imageview2
            case R.id.b2: {
                v.startAnimation(anim);

                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);

                break;
            }
//imageview3
            case R.id.b3: {

                v.startAnimation(anim);
                playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.b4: {

                v.startAnimation(anim);
                playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.b5: {
                v.startAnimation(anim);
                playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.b6: {
                v.startAnimation(anim);
                playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.b7: {
                v.startAnimation(anim);
                playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);
                break;
            }


        }
    }}

//метод через,который пытаюсь воспроизводить мелодии



private void playSample(int resid) {

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

    } else {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            afd.close();


        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас нет ошибки. Вы как написали - так оно и работает. Сначала останавливает плеер и сразу запускает по новой. Вам бы почитать что-нить на тему того как условные операторы работают. В вашем случае, вам весь остаток метода playSample (т.е. блоки try и catch) надо обернуть в else.

Comment: @upward, так... теперь  несколько запутался... А чем предыдущий вариант кода не устраивал?..

Comment: @upwardm, ну... Верните как было... Я уже не помню почему вас изначальный то вариант не устроил

Comment: @upward, если я правильно понял, вам надо в активити завести int переменную, хранящую ID последней нажатой кнопки. Если пи нажатии есть совпадение и музыка не играет, то запустить, иначе - остановить

Comment: @upward, да ID это `v.getId()` проверки организуются `if`-ом

Comment: Повторю - создайте переменную для хранения последнего нажатого ID. При нажатии сравните это значение с текущим ID и одновременно играется ли музыка.Вы же написали код коий всегда true

Comment: @upward, я мог бы вам написать рабочий код, это всего 2-3 строки, но вам это не поможет, ибо нет базовых знаний. Вам надо взять и прочитать первые несколько глав любой книжки про яву.

Comment: @upward, да, полностью не то, что я говорю. Вы даже переменную в актвивити не создали, и значения в неё не записываете, и не считываете их.

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда спасибо @ЮрийСПб

То что мне нужно:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_pause);
        stopAnimation();



            if (saveID  ==v.getId()&mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            else{
                switch ( saveID = v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.b1: {
                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.b2: {
                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.b3: {


                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.b4: {


                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);


                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.b5: {

                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.b6: {

                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.b7: {

                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```